# loDash -- Is there a way to simplify for readability

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the logic worked out but wanted to find a more readable (and maintainable) way to write this:

```
let labels = _.map(_.keys( _.groupBy(sd, 'month')), (i) => {
      return months[i].abr;
    });
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wynnewade/pen/NXdxmV?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method chaining:

```
const labels = _(sd).groupBy('month').keys().map(i => months[i].abr);
```

The following might semantically even better express your intention:

```
const labels = _(sd).map('month').uniq().map(i => months[i].abr);
```

```js
const months = [
    {},
    {
      abr: 'Jan',
      full: 'January'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Feb',
      full: 'February'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Mar',
      full: 'March'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Apr',
      full: 'April'
    },
    {
      abr: 'May',
      full: 'May'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Jun',
      full: 'June'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Jul',
      full: 'July'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Aug',
      full: 'August'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Sep',
      full: 'Septmeber'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Oct',
      full: 'October'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Nov',
      full: 'November'
    },
    {
      abr: 'Dec',
      full: 'December'
    }
  ];

const sd = [
    { id: 1, year: 2017, month: 10, service: 3, val: 20 },
    { id: 2, year: 2017, month: 10, service: 1, val: 50 },
    { id: 3, year: 2017, month: 10, service: 2, val: 25 },
    { id: 4, year: 2017, month: 11, service: 3, val: 40 },
    { id: 5, year: 2017, month: 11, service: 1, val: 30 },
    { id: 6, year: 2017, month: 11, service: 2, val: 35 },
    { id: 7, year: 2017, month: 12, service: 3, val: 30 },
    { id: 8, year: 2017, month: 12, service: 1, val: 20 },
    { id: 9, year: 2017, month: 12, service: 2, val: 50 }
  ];

const labels1 = _(sd).groupBy('month').keys().map(i => months[i].abr);

console.log(labels1);

const labels2 = _(sd).map('month').uniq().map(i => months[i].abr);

console.log(labels2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get an error of "_ is not a function" where before lodash was recognized ... the error points to _(sd) ... however, I should say I just abstracted my issue for simplicity and when I add your solution to my vue component, I get that error.

Comment: I went off the code in Codepen to create the snippet above. It seems to work fine running it in Stackoverflow...

Comment: is definitely working here ... you don't happen to know vue, do you?

Comment: Nope. Have been using Angular and some React lately... You could ask a new question about the Vue-specific case.

Answer (score 0):

It could be simplified for readability using chaining:

```
let labels = _(sd)
    .groupBy('month')
    .keys()
    .map(key => months[key])
    .value();
```